# How to rebuild openCV-python with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, fedora, opencv3.0

I have installed openCV-Python from Pre-built Binaries version on fedora 26.
using this command

```
yum install numpy opencv* 
import cv2
print ("opencv version: ",cv2.__version_) #python3
#(opencv version: 3.2.0)
```

I want to read a *.mp4 video

```
video=cv2.VideoCapture("out.mp4")
```

but it does not work and gives these error

```
Failed to query video capabilities: Inappropriate ioctl for device
libv4l2: error getting capabilities: Inappropriate ioctl for device
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: device out.mp4: Unable to query number of channels
warning: GStreamer: unable to query duration of stream (/builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-3.2.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:846)
```

(this problem is common!). I check if the opencv is build with ffmpeg support using this command:

```
python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -i ffmpeg
```

that gives me `FFMPEG:                      NO`

I want how to rebuilt OpenCV with ffmeg support support

Comment: Had same problem, solved with unofficial build from [pypi.org/project/opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), and installing. The current build (opencv4.4) includes ffmpeg.

Answer (score -1):

Why not using a package manager ? If you use Anaconda, you just have to go with

```
 conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

It should install opencv with ffmpeg included

Comment: This does not answer the question!